# 16.04 Installation stuck on "Creating ext4 file system", previously had trouble with partitioning

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 over a virus-filled Windows 8.1 desktop. I've tried using DBAN to wipe out the Windows 8.1 partition, but the USB I installed it on doesn't show up on the boot menu. I think the virus-filled Windows 8.1 partition is what's giving me problems, but I can't be sure.

My installation usually crashes on the step where I have to create a partition. After launching Windows and restarting about 15 times, I've somehow gotten Ubuntu to start installing, but it has now been stuck on "Creating ext4 file system" for over an hour. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What partition option did you select?

Comment: If you don't care about the Windows stuff, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and run `gparted` and lay down a new partition table. That should wipe the drive for you. Then you should be able to install Ubuntu.,